# EF model with list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'll create app to saving gym results.
I have class Exercise:

```
public class Exercise
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public string Name { get; protected set; }
    public Category Category { get; protected set; }
}
```

and class TrainingPlan which contain List of Exercise :

```
public class TrainingPlan
{
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }
    public string Name { get; protected set; }
    public IEnumerable<Exercise> Exercises { get; protected set; }
}
```

I create EntityFramework DbContext:

```
public class GymContext : DbContext
{
    public GymContext(DbContextOptions<GymContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Exercise> Exercises { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TrainingPlan> TrainingPlans { get; set; }
}
```

And then I used command add-migration and update-database. For table with exercise, EF was added additional field with TrainingPlanId. So now I can assignee Exercise only to one TrainingPlan. But I want assigne Exercise for a few Plans, what is the best solution for this case?

Comment: Looks that you want a many-to-many relationship. Please take a look in this site: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Do you develop with ef core or ef? For ef core, try to refer [Many-to-many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many)

Answer (score 0):

Thx for help, I use many to many.
It's solve, I crate new class:

```
public class TrainingPlanExercise
{
    public Guid TrainigPlanId { get; protected set; }
    public TrainingPlan TrainigPlan { get; protected set; }
    public Guid ExerciseId { get; protected set; }
    public Exercise Exercise { get; protected set; }
}
```

And in TrainingPlan I replace List of Exercise to List of TrainingPlanExercise.

My EntityFramework DbContext now look that:

```
public class GymContext : DbContext
{
    public GymContext(DbContextOptions<GymContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Exercise> Exercises { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TrainingPlan> TrainingPlans { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TrainingPlanExercise> TrainingPlanExercises { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TrainingPlanExercise>()
            .HasKey(e => new { e.ExerciseId, e.TrainigPlanId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<TrainingPlanExercise>()
            .HasOne(x => x.TrainigPlan)
            .WithMany(x => x.Exercises)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.TrainigPlanId);
     }
}
```

Unfortunately I'm stuck again. When I want get from DB single record TrainingPlan using this method:

```
        public TrainingPlan Get(Guid id)
        => _context.TrainingPlans.Include(x => x.Exercises).Single(x => x.Id == id);
```

I receive record with null Exercise in List TrainingPlanExercise.

Should I add something more to DbContext or is there other solution?

BTW. I using EF core.